# Spring Exception Handling - how to use ExceptionResolver and @ExceptionHandler at the same time

Tags: spring, exception, portlet

I developed a web application where form validation exceptions are supposed to be handled by @ExceptionHandler (needs to be flexible) and general system exceptions by SimpleMappingExceptionResolver (doing stuff like email notification etc.).

Problem is, that if I use both, exceptions that are mapped for @ExceptionHandler don't get to the @ExceptionHandler but are grabbed by ExceptionResolver as defaultError.

Any idea what to do to make it work together ?

```
@ExceptionHandler(ValidatorException.class)
public String handleFormException(ValidatorException ex, ActionRequest actionRequest) {
    logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    //TODO make conditions
    return "mainOrderForm";
}
```

---

```
@ActionMapping(params = "action=addDocOrder")
public void addDocOrder(@ModelAttribute("order") CstOrderBeanImpl orderBean,
        BindingResult result, ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse response) 
        throws PortalException, SystemException, ValidatorException {
    logger.info("Adding Form Order");
    Calendar cal = TimeUtils.getEuDeadLine(orderBean);
    orderBean.setDeadLine(cal.getTime());
    ValidatorException ve = validateService.validate(orderBean, result, actionRequest, validator);
    if (ve != null) throw ve;
(...)
```

In DispatcherPortlet, there is

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    // Trigger after-completion for thrown exception.
    triggerAfterActionCompletion(mappedHandler, interceptorIndex, processedRequest, response, ex);
(...)
```

Which checks for interceptors, but none exists, so it does the default...

I just point out, that it's Portlet environment, there is usually less "views"...driven by parameters..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe as a workaround in ExceptionResolver you could dynamically invoke a handler method of your choice.

```
public ModelAndView resolveException(RenderRequest req, RenderResponse res, Object handler,Exception exc) {
    if(exc instanceof ValidatorException) {
        try {
            java.lang.reflect.Method m = handler.getClass().getMethod("someMethod", (Class<?>)null /* method parameters? */);
            m.invoke(handler,new Object[]{(ValidatorException)exc,req/*, res - maybe?*/});
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // Handle exception
        }
    }

    // Send email of the error etc..
}
```

It's not exactly an elegant solution, but should work..

Comment: Hi heikkim, this is exactly what I've finally done, I didn't invoke the method on the handler but I just checked for this (exc instanceof ValidatorException) and I did what I needed. But what you suggest makes more sense, it's more transparent when the logic is in handler, not in the exceptionResolver

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you put at least one Exception Resolver to the app-context DispatcherServlet stops instantiating default ones (**AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver** in your case).

Be sure to put both **AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver** and **SimpleMappingExceptionResolver** to the app-context and also impose their ordering.

See [my post](http://forum.springsource.org/showpost.php?p=347448&postcount=3) for detailed explanation.

Comment: @IhorKaharlichenko Hey, link is broken!

Comment: @GC_ Hey, it wasn't me who has retired the Spring forums, I promise! The rest of the answer contains all you need to fix the problem. Just put those two beans in the context using whatever method is used in your app, be it XML definition or annotations and you should be golden.

Comment: I dislike that they closed it.  I keep getting links there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Portlet environment, but perhaps you need to declare `AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver` as well.

Comment: hi, that doesn't help, AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver is in the context by default